# add a value that contains commas to an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to create an array which will give me the following json encoded output:

```
   {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":[123,123]}
```

The question is about value 3 - it actually represents 2 numbers that i'm querying from my sqlite database that i want to save into one field, delimited by comma, and enclosed within square brackets.

can you tell me how to accomplish this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a sub-array value:

```
$array['key3'] = array(123, 123);
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zqfmyX).

Comment: Ok... i've tried that in a little test page and it gives me the results i want... but now that i've implemented into my loop, it's giving me an error about an undefined index on the line where i'm creating the mini array.

Comment: @dot: Try to grok the error message. In any case, if you still have problems it's best to edit the question accordingly.

Comment: nevermind, i'm an idiot.  it was a typo.  your solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the entire array like this:

```
$json = array(
  'key1' => 'value1',
  'key2' => 'value2',
  'key3' => array(
    123,
    123
  )
)
```

If you are filling it in one value at a time, you can do:

```
$json = array();
$json['key1'] = 'value1';
$json['key2'] = 'value2';
$json['key3'] = array();
$json['key3'][] = 123;
$json['key3'][] = 123;
```

And then you convert it JSON by calling:

```
$json_string = json_encode($json)
```

Comment: my code looks like this:  foreach($result as $row)
                                {
                                                                                                $resultArray[] = array('value1' => $row['val1'],'value2' => $row['val2'], 'value3' => array($row['val3'],$row['val4']));
                                }                                                i'm getting an error about an undefined index.

Comment: I've also tried defining the "sub array" on a line right before adding to $resultArray[].  eg) $subarray=array($row['val2'],$row['val3']);  but i get the same error message.

Comment: @dot, if you're getting an undefined index error at that point, it means that either $row['val2'] doesn't actually exist or $row['val3'] doesn't actually exist. You can imply that you know this by putting an "@" sign in front of the variable, so $subarray=array(@$row['val2'], @row['val3']), but that's going to be bad practice in the long run if you expect something to be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj=json_decode($json_string);
print_r($obj->key3);
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want is

```
$my_array = array(  key1=> 'value1',
                    key2=> 'value1',
                    key3=> array(123, 123)
);
```